# Remove duplicates based on substring in Python

Tags: python, text, duplicates, flat-file

i have the following code for detecting duplicates in a file and outputing them in 3 separate files, one for non-duplicates, one for duplicates (x2) and one for duplicates (> x2). The first file, holds only lines that had no duplicates in the original file. (It doesnt remove any duplicate lines found, it keeps singles).

```
import os
import sys
import time
import collections


file_in = sys.argv[1]
file_ot = str(file_in) + ".proc"
file_ot2 = str(file_in) + ".proc2"
file_ot3 = str(file_in) + ".proc3"


counter = 0        

dict_in = collections.defaultdict(list)  
with open(file_in, "r") as f:  
    for line in f:  
        #print("read line: " + str(line))
        counter += 1
        fixed_line = line.strip()
        line_list = fixed_line.split(";")
        key = line_list[0][:12]
        print(":Key: " + str(key))
        dict_in[key].append(line)


with open(file_ot, "w") as f1, open(file_ot2, "w") as f2, open(file_ot3, "w") as f3:
    selector = {1: f1, 2: f2}  
    for values in dict_in.values():  
        if len(values) == 1:
            f1.writelines(values)
        elif len(values) == 2:
            f2.writelines(values)
        else:
            f3.writelines(values)



print("Read: " + str(counter) + " lines")
```

The above code works, but for v large files (~1g) it takes about ten minutes to chomp through them on my system. I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the speed of this code, or any suggestions in that direction. Thank you in advance!

Input data example:

```
0000AAAAAAAA;X;;X;
0000AAAAAAAA;X;X;;
0000BBBBBBBB;X;;;
0000CCCCCCCC;;X;;
0000DDDDDDDD;X;;X;
0000DDDDDDDD;X;X;;
0000DDDDDDDD;X;X;X;X
0000EEEEEEEE;X;X;X;X
0000FFFFFFFF;X;;;
0000GGGGGGGG;X;;X;
0000HHHHHHHH;X;X;;
0000JJJJJJJJ;X;X;;
```

Expected output:

```
FILE1:
0000BBBBBBBB;X;;;
0000CCCCCCCC;;X;;
0000EEEEEEEE;X;X;X;X
0000FFFFFFFF;X;;;
0000GGGGGGGG;X;;X;
0000HHHHHHHH;X;X;;
0000JJJJJJJJ;X;X;;

FILE2:
0000AAAAAAAA;X;;X;
0000AAAAAAAA;X;X;;

FILE3:
0000DDDDDDDD;X;;X;
0000DDDDDDDD;X;X;;
0000DDDDDDDD;X;X;X;X
```

Comment: Show your input data and expeced output.

Comment: Your example might be a bit erroneous, as I wouldn't call `0000AAAAAAAA;X;;X;`  and `0000AAAAAAAA;X;X;;` duplicates, since they differ in the end. Or do you always want to compare only the first 12 characters, as I would assume from the part `key = line_list[0][:12]`?

Comment: also, if you were on a UNIX system, I'm optimistic that using `sort` and `uniq` would be faster than Python.

Comment: Its not a unix system, this is run on windows, and i m only interested in duplicates found in the first 12 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 543MB of random text file to test it.

```
import time

myList = []

start = time.time()
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        myList.insert(len(myList), line)

with open("dupListaOne.txt", "w") as f1, open ("dupListMore.txt","w") as f2, open("UniqueList.txt","w") as f3:
    new_list = sorted(set(myList))
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
            a = myList.count(new_list[i])
            if ((a-1) == 1):
                f1.write("%s\n" % new_list[i] + " " + str(a-1))
            elif ((a-1) > 1):
                f2.write("%s\n" % new_list[i] + " " + str(a-1))
            else:
                f3.write("%s\n" % new_list[i] + " " + str(a-1))
end = time.time()
print("Time: ",end - start)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Elapsed time: 123.82529425621033 sec. ~ 2 min.